# Please -Using Python What am I missing here ? "while len (equation) > 1 and hasPrdDiv(equation): equation is not defined"

Tags: python

```
#def PrdDiv(equation)

import math

def hasPrdDiv(equation):
    for elem in equation:
        if elem == "*" or elem == "/":
            return True
    return False
```

def main():
        equation=input("Enter your equation and ensure space between each inputs: ").split()
        #print("Equation is:" , equation)

```
i = 0
i = i + 1

while len (equation) > 1 and hasPrdDiv(equation):  #Fails here
        if equation [i] == "*" or equation [i] == "/":
                equation = process(equation, i)

while len (equation) > 1:
        if equation [i] =="+" or equation [i] =="-":
                equation=process(equation,i)

print("Equation is:" , equation)

#b="".join(equation)
#print(b)

main()
```

Comment: Your code is in Python 3 and you are running in Python 2, that is what this error means.

Comment: Your indentation is b0rked, please fix it.